# Server call on constructor vs ngOnInit

Tags: angular

According to angular.io , it says calling server on constructor is a bad idea and we should do it on other hookup methods of component lifecycle. Why is it so ? . is it about clean separation of responsibility  ?
Code:

```
ngOnInit():void{
 this.heroes=this.heroService.getHeroes(); //better
}


constructor(private heroService:HeroService){

  this.heroes=this.heroService.getHeroes(); //this is bad
}
```

Comment: According to Angular.io, author said that writing code on `ngOnInit` is much easier for testing also. Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#!#the-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook